# Android - ViewPager - Update UI on first Tab when second Tab is changed (swipe detecting)

Tags: android

Here is code of MainActivity:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabPagerAdapter tabPagerAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private String[] tabNames = { "Main", "Settings", "Rules" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        tabPagerAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabPagerAdapter);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabNames[i])
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int postion) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(postion);
                if(postion==1){
                    View view = viewPager.getChildAt(postion);
                    set_lang(view);
                }
                if(postion==0){
                    View view = viewPager.getChildAt(postion);
                    set_flag(view);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void set_lang(View view){
        MainFrame.preferences = getSharedPreferences("flag", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        MainFrame.editor = MainFrame.preferences.edit();

        RadioGroup radio = (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        int radioButtonID = radio.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RadioButton radioBut = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(radioButtonID);
        String lang = (String) radioBut.getTag();

        MainFrame.editor.putString("lang", lang);
        MainFrame.editor.apply();
    }

    public View set_flag(View view) {
        Button btn_flag = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_flag);
        MainFrame.preferences = getSharedPreferences("flag", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String lang = MainFrame.preferences.getString("lang","");
        if(lang.equals("english")){
            btn_flag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.eng_flag);
        }
        if(lang.equals("russian")){
            btn_flag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rus_flag);
        }
        if(lang.equals("german")){
            btn_flag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.german_flag);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is code of TabPageAdapter:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                return new MainFrame();
            case 1:
                return new Settings();
            case 2:
                return new Rules();
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

I know, that I must change onPageSelected(int postion) method to catch page changing, but it does not work. Currently it dont change nothing, and when i switch from third tab to second - app is crashing.[image]
For better understanding: I want to change button background on first tab, when user switch language on second tab, using radiobuttons(radiogroup).
See the screenshot.

Comment: what is really your problem? would you be little specific?

Comment: provide the crash log?

Comment: Change flag on first tab, when user change language on second

Comment: @junaid hafeez
For better understanding: I want to change button background on first tab, when user switch language on second tab, using radiobuttons(radiogroup). See the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve this using `public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` method of Fragment.

When the user changes anything in Settings Fragment store that in Preference and when the user switches to Main Fragment, read the value of the newly selected Value from  Preference inside **setUserVisibleHint** method while checking for isVisibleToUser, then read the value from Preference and change the background with updated value.

Answer (score 1):

@Nagesh Jatagond, thank you for advice, I finaly find solution!

Settings.java:

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible)
    {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
        View v = getView();
        if (!visible && v!=null){
            set_lang(v);
        }
    }
```

Main.java:

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible)
    {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
        View v = getView();
        if (!visible && v!=null){
            set_flag(v);
        }
        if (visible && v!=null){
            set_flag(v);
        }
    }
```